# Multiple dex files define Lcom/getkeepsafe/relinker/SystemLibraryLoader;

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am facing this problem when am trying to build my project -> Multiple dex files define Lcom/getkeepsafe/relinker/SystemLibraryLoader;

I have tried to clean the .gradle, deleting the build folder and reinstalling dependencies but its still not working.

Here is my build.gradle:moduleapp

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
defaultConfig {
applicationId 'com.taxiapp.passenger'
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 26
versionCode 13
versionName '1.0.3'
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
}
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
productFlavors {
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
}
/* IMPORTANT :

Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error /
dependencies {
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
})
compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.0.0@aar') {
transitive = true
}
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.0'
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.2@aar'

compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

// compile('pl.droidsonroids.relinker:1.2.2'){
// exclude module: 'pl.droidsonroids.relinker:1.2.2'
// }

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
compile 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:material-design-dimens:1.4'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my build.gradle:projectmodule

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
// maven {
// url 'https://maven.google.com/'
// name 'Google'
// }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please advice what i can do to solve this proplem

Comment: update eclipse (Help->Check for updates)

Answer (score 0):

Add this string inside dependecies{} in build.gradle:moduleapp

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.3.1' //this string
}
```

it seems that you are using a very old ready-made script, I advise you to do everything by yourself.

I recommend you to use 'implement' or 'api' instead of 'compile'

Also don't use

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
```

always use a specific version to avoid other 'Multiple dex files define' issues, for example.

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
```

don't forget to rebuild the project by following step in toolbar-menu: Build -> Rebuild Project.